Cannot connect to psql on postgres kubernetes pod
I am trying to create a minimal postgres deployment with helm with the admin user called postgres and a user called user.
I am hardcoding the passwords for now, the pod is being created correctly but i can't access to the database!
Here's my terraform code:
resource "helm_release" "postgres" {
  name       = "pg-${var.namespace}"
  namespace  = var.namespace
  chart      = "postgresql"
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  version    = "13.4.4"
  values = [templatefile("manifests/postgres-values.yaml", {
    fullnameOverride        = "pg-${var.namespace}"
    pg_spot                 = var.pg_spot
    pg_affinity             = var.pg_affinity
    pg_nodeSelector         = var.pg_nodeSelector
    pg_tolerations          = var.pg_tolerations
    db_pass                 = "postgres"
  })]

  set_sensitive {
    name  = "db_pass"
    value = "postgres"
  }
}

and here's how my manifests/postgres-values.yaml looks like:
fullnameOverride: ${fullnameOverride}
global:
  storageClass: managed-csi
  postgresql:
    auth:
      postgresPassword: "postgresadmin"
      username: "user"
      password: "postgres"
    service:
      ports:
        postgresql: 5432

primary:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 256Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 256Mi
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    size: 1Gi
    labels:
      purpose: pg
  persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy:
    enabled: true
    whenDeleted: Retain
  ${indent(2, pg_nodeSelector)}
  ${indent(2, pg_tolerations)}

architecture: standalone

I get my helm chart deployed correctly and my pod is running but when I execute:
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
and provide postgresadmin as password, i get this error:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" 
As if the user is not being created !!
enter image description here
Any ideas?

Could it be that you created the postgres instance before already with another user ? Since persistency is enabled, the user and password will only be configured on the first startup. Remove the PVC and install the helm chart again. More info here

The postgresPassword is stored within the persistent volume and only set on first deployment. You may have deployed the postgres chart already before with another (or unset) postgresPassword.
Due to enabled persistency you have to remove the PVC manually and then deploy the helmchart again.
